# Strapi congela ao selecionar o banco de dados

Tags: javascript, api

Hoje resolvi me aventurar com o **CMF [Strapi](https://strapi.io/)**, segui diversos tutoriais, mas ele sempre congela na parte de selecionar o banco, mesmo eu iniciando os bancos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mongo iniciado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Momento que o Strapi para de funcionar

Alguém tem ideia do por que de acontecer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera, por algum motivo misterioso, o comando `strapi new nome_projeto` não funcionou para mim usando o **CMD** e nem o **Power Shell**, porém ao tentar no **Git Bash** ele executou normalmente. Então se alguém passar por um problema similar, talvez isso resolva.